# VS Code, Python, Terminal - Create database from command line; error: "The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language."

Tags: python, sqlite, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am having an issue with running Python code from the command line terminal in VS Code. For the record, I am using Windows 10. I am attempting to create an SQLite database for my flask application, and to do so I have set up my virtual environment, venv, and have navigated to the directory containing my project with cd. My Python file is called app.py. This file contains the following code in particular:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I then used the command (from within the venv) `from app import db`, which *should* create the file called test.db in my directory folder containing app.py (plus my html/css). However, I am getting the following error:

```
At line:1 char:1
+ from app import db
+ ~~~~
The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReservedKeywordNotAllowed
```

I made sure I am using Python in the terminal, rather than powershell (although I tried that, just for fun, and it didn't work, either). I am using Python 3.8.1, which I have never had issues running before, so I don't think that's really the problem. I tried prepending `python` and `python3` to the command `from app import db`, but for some odd reason that just brought up the Windows app store to try to get me to download Python (which I obviously already have). I have looked at similar questions/answers on SO, but I have not found anything that resolves my particular issue.

Is this a VS Code issue specifically? Where am I going wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Below is my launch.json file, as requested by Klaus D., located in my project folder:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way I should be editing this?

Comment: Show us your `launch.json`! If you don't launch via the "play" button. show us exactly how you do it!

Comment: use the command `python app.py`. Powershell can't parse python files

Comment: not very handy to create a variable with the same name as a module: `app`

Comment: @KlausD. I have updated the question with my launch.json

Answer (score 2):

please make sure that first you type: python
this will activate the python interpreter with the >>> sign on the left